# window.location not working when button is clicked

Tags: javascript

Check out this link:
http://humorjots.com/Barry/BarryWashington.htm

The part in the script that says:

```
if(emailInput.value != '' && zipInput.value != ''){
    window.location = "sea206.html";
}
```

for some reason doesn't work in loading sea206.html. However when you go to type `window.location = 'sea206.html'` in the developers console, it loads the page. I don't understand why it won't work when the button is clicked.
The if statement does work. If an alert is inserted within the statement, it runs run when the button is clicked.

Comment: maybe the conditions are not met, try printing your values first

Comment: Do you have an action or method attached to the form? They can often cause problems

Comment: You could call `emailInput.click()` and then check if value if `''`, and similarly for the `zipInput`. The auto-filled values make it not enter the `if` statement.

Comment: the form was submitted when you've clicked the button, that is why it won't go to your desired location. You should add "return false;" on your submitButton.onclick function to resolve that issue. I have updated answer below. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happened on your code was it performs the default function of button on  which will automatically submits the form.

Solution to this is that you must add return false on your submitButton.onclick function so that it will not submit the form and redirects to your desired location

```
if( emailInput.value != '' && zipInput.value != '')
{
    window.location = "/Barry/sea206.html";
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this does work too. Thank you! I saw Neil's answer first, but he has a way higher reputation, so you get the check. Thanks.

Comment: thats ok. anyway I'm glad that I could help you. :)

Answer (score 3):

The default action of the button is to submit the form. This overrides your location change. These days you don't need to include the `<form>` element if you're not actually going to submit anything. However if you do need a non-submitting button then you need to use the `type="button"` attribute.

Comment: Jesus you're right. That's the weirdest thing to say `type='button'`inside of a button. Wow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When I go to your page and click on both input fields and let them empty it will automatically filled out with your Placeholder text. So it never will be empty.

When I type `emailInput.value` into the console I'll get `"Email"`. Analog to ZipCode.

So you should try

```
if (emailInput.value != 'Email' && zipInput.value != 'Zip Code') { 
  window.location.href = "sea206.html"; 
}
```

I read your script code and you wrote `submitbutton.onclick ...` Try to make the onclick event within your button:

```
<button id="submitButton" onclick='javascript:submitForm();' />
```

With this javascript code in your `<script>...</script>` part:

```
function submitForm() {
  if (emailInput.value != 'Email' && zipInput.value != 'Zip Code') { 
    window.location.href = "sea206.html"; 
  }  
}
```

Does it work?

Comment: I know they wont be empty, that's what I'm implying when I say `!=''` as in not equal to nothing.

Comment: Yes thats correct, but that's not really the point of your problem. I will edit my answer.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I don't think that's the problem, because even with my current code, when I put an alert directly before the `window.location` the function works once the button is clicked when there is stuff in the inputs.